# Which is the most correct method for sending JSON for android Webservice?

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-volley

Which is the correct way for sending POST response for webservices for Android app.

**METHOD #1 : Send As Array**

```js
[  
   {  
      "Field1":1,
      "Field2":1,
      "Field3":{  
         "Field4":1,
         "Field5":"Restaurant"
      },
      "Field6":"xyz",
      "Field7":null,
     
   }
]
```

**METHOD #2 : Send As Object**

```js
{  
   "Message":"Good",
   "Result":[  
      {  
         "Field1":1,
         "Field2":1,
         "Field3":{  
            "Field4":1,
            "Field5":"Restaurant"
         },
         "Field6":"xyz",
         "Field7":null
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 2: send As Object is good enough. In this way developers can check the status of that response from your message.

Answer (score 2):

That purely depends upon your requirement. 

Having an array in **Method 1** removes extra object creation for parsing the request.

Where as in some cases if your application include other webservice calls which follow different standard for status management like others commented, it's better to follow that only. **Method 2** definitely includes error management and more preferred.

Answer (score 1):

**Obviously 2nd one**

**Step 1** for every operation, we need to know- "Is there any error or got success !".

**Step 2** Now get the "data section" or "Error message".

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have to got with second one with one more params like `status` `true/false` so you can identify your status based on it.